# ffmpeg fails with error Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output'

Tags: ffmpeg

I copied the code used to concatenate mp4 files as given [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

it fails with the error

```
[NULL @ 0x7ff620828600] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output'

output: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ffmpeg` does not know what format `output` should be.

To save in an mp4 container, use `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4`.

Comment: I can see where the OP was confused. I updated the wiki page and added extensions to the example commands.